# Плохо ли создавать в подпроцессах потоки?

Tags: python, многопоточность, multiprocessing

Вся суть вопроса в названии.

Плохим ли будет создание приложения, которое создает child-процессы, которые в свою очередь создают потоки для решения IO задач?

Comment: Принципиально ничего плохого в этом нет. Каждый инструмент для своих задач. И у потоков и у процессов есть свои плюсы/минусы. В конкретном случае, надо смотреть - как и любой инструмент эти тоже могут быть использованы не к месту.

Comment: Но ведь на подпроцессы начинает влиять GIL, вследствие того, что мы в подпроцессе создаем еще и потоки? Я прав?

Comment: GIL начинает влиять, только я не понимаю ваше "но". С той детализацией, что вы описали ("IO задачи") никаких принципиальных противопоказаний нет, так как для IO задач GIL не будет узким местом.